# Issues with calculating gradient descent operation

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

I have this issue when using gradient ascent. I have some synthetic data and after my first iteration the objective function decreases and from the second iteration it keeps on increasing. Is it possible for a convex function. I also have the learning rate very low 0.001. Any suggestions.

Comment: How do you calculate your derivatives? What software package are you  using?

Comment: By definition you don't have an ascent algorithm. Let's see some code.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something is probably wrong in your code or you have your step size (learning rate) set too large. If you coded it properly, the objective function at iteration t+1 should always be lower than at iteration t. This feature is what makes it an "ascent" algorithm. We might be able to give you more insight if you provide your code and, better yet, a reproducible example.